# Is it possible to set a constraint to a type attribute in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I want to create a type with an attribute which should be expect three possible values. Something like following statement:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS OBJECT(
    attrib1 VARCHAR2(30),
    attrib2 VARCHAR2(30),
    attrib3 VARCHAR2(30) -- this attribute should accept three possible values: val1, val2, or val3
);
```

Is there any way to do this, just like in the case of tables?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No there is no way to do that

Answer (score 1):

You may use [custom type constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/system-defined-and-user-defined-constructors.html#GUID-AACBEBFC-4E97-43D2-BE9B-2142C7DF3BD8) and perform this check inside PL/SQL code.

```
create type my_type as object(
  attrib1 varchar2(30),
  attrib2 varchar2(30),
  attrib3 varchar2(30),
  
  constructor function my_type (
    attrib1 in varchar2,
    attrib2 in varchar2,
    attrib3 in varchar2
  ) return self as result
);
/

create type body my_type as
  constructor function my_type (
    attrib1 in varchar2,
    attrib2 in varchar2,
    attrib3 in varchar2
  ) return self as result
  as
    invalid_attr_value exception;
    pragma exception_init(invalid_attr_value, -20001);
  begin
    if attrib3 not in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid attrib3 value supplied');
    end if;
    self.attrib1 := attrib1;
    self.attrib2 := attrib2;
    self.attrib3 := attrib3;
    return;
  end;
end;/
```

```
with a(col) as (
  select my_type('a', 'b', 'val1')
  from dual
)
select
  a.col.attrib1,
  a.col.attrib2,
  a.col.attrib3
from a a
```

| COL.ATTRIB1 | COL.ATTRIB2 | COL.ATTRIB3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | val1 |

```
with a(col) as (
  select my_type('a', 'b', 'val10')
  from dual
)
select
  a.col.attrib1,
  a.col.attrib2,
  a.col.attrib3
from a a
```

```
ORA-20001: Invalid attrib3 value supplied
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_INSFSVTZEJFLABZQAKDJ.MY_TYPE", line 12
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ab0_8MmO)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you'd be happy with, but - unfortunately - it won't work:

```
SQL> create or replace type my_type as object
  2  (attrib1 varchar2(30),
  3   attrib2 varchar2(30),
  4   attrib3 varchar2(30) check(attrib3 in ('A', 'B'))
  5  );
  6  /
create or replace type my_type as object
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
ORA-06550: line 4, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK" when expecting one of the following:
:= ) , not null default external character
The symbol ":= was inserted before "CHECK" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00565: MY_TYPE must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)
```

Therefore, create the type *as is* ...

```
SQL> create or replace type my_type as object
  2  (attrib1 varchar2(30),
  3   attrib2 varchar2(30),
  4   attrib3 varchar2(30)
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.
```

... and then apply check constraint on `attrib3` while using that type in `create table` statement, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test of my_type
  2  (attrib1 primary key,
  3   attrib2 not null,
  4   attrib3 default 'A' check (attrib3 in ('A', 'B'))
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this, just like in the case of tables?

No, you cannot apply a `CHECK` constraint to an `OBJECT` data-type.

From the [`CONSTRAINT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/constraint.html):

> Constraint clauses can appear in the following statements:
>
> - `CREATE TABLE` (see [`CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6))
> - `ALTER TABLE` (see [`ALTER TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877))
> - `CREATE VIEW` (see [`CREATE VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30))
> - `ALTER VIEW` (see [`ALTER VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-VIEW.html#GUID-0DEDE960-B481-4B55-8027-EA9E4C863625))

So you cannot create a constraint in a `CREATE TYPE` or an `ALTER TYPE` statement.